# Swift3 - Background Fetch Crash on Debug

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, background-fetch

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    print(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

This is my code and when I Debug in XCode > Simulate background fetch my app crash without reason. I activated in Capabilities>Background modes>Background fetch... any ideas?

It crash only on iPhone in simulator I don't have problems.

Comment: In which line your app crashed ?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/01/13/ios9-background-execution/

Comment: @MuhammadNoman Swift 3 is on iOS 10 XCode 8

Comment: no matter you are using swift 3 , just take a concept from here not follow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your above description, I tried it in my project but it works fine and `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` is working in background also.

First I try without adding this property, but performFetchWithCompletionHandler not called. So,Try to add this in info.plist file

```
 <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
    </array>
```

It will solve my problem

Comment: nope i receive
`libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
    0x182d38164 <+0>: movn   x16, #0x1e
    0x182d38168 <+4>: svc    #0x80
->  0x182d3816c <+8>: ret    
`

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov Would you like to share your project with me? So I can understand it, If you dont mind

Comment: Jecky it works on simulator bro, but on my iPhone crashes

Comment: In Xcode 8.2.1, you have to click "Continue program execution" (Play Button in Debug Area)